# Both `systemd` and `upstart` (init) installed - which package(s) determents what's default?

Tags: boot, upstart, systemd, init

I've been playing around (a bit too much?) with "Unrecognized Tasks" in `aptitude`, and have installed lots of extra-packages - mostly to be able to freely choose between different desktop-managers...  At some point during this, I apparently went from using `systemd` to using `upstart/init` as my ancestral process.  Both `systemd` and `upstart` are installed however.

I know it's possible to select the other ancestor from the "Advanced Option"-entry in the GRUB boot-menu.  I suppose I also could edit */etc/grub.d* - or even the GRUB command-line at boot-time.

However, what/which package(s) - or possibly config-file - is it that actually sets the default ancestor-process as either `systemd` or `upstart/init` - ie. among other things decide what will be the degfault entry in GRUB?  It's obviously (somewhat) separate from the actual installation, since both flavors can be installed at once...

Comment: Welcome to Linux where there are six ways to Sunday for doing the same thing.  I've been struggling with 6 different ways of suspending / resuming for a while now. I don't have an answer but have empathy.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  :-D  I've actually been using Linux since around 1998 and consider all the ways of doing things a serious perk...  However, I sort of lost the thread when Ubuntu switched to `upstart` - and `systemd` made all just worse!  How I miss the good ol' days with `init` (the original) and SysV runlevels - and good GUI-tools to manipulate them!

Comment: Well if you've been using it since 1998 you can help me with all my systemd questions :)

Comment: Does https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart help?